# VueJS Binding same variable to multiple of the same component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I have a basic page with VueJS as follows:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<p>{{message}}</p>',
  props: ["message"]
});

new Vue({
  el: '#theParent',
  data() {
    return {
      message: "It works!"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/2.3.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="theParent">
    <child v-bind:message="message"></child>
    <child v-bind:message="message"></child>
    <child v-bind:message="message"></child>
</div>
```

The message *It works!* shows up three times as expected, but if I remove `v-bind:message="message"` on my `<child>` components it doesn't work. As all my `<child>` components will require the value of `message` from the parent, is there a way to specify this once in the VueJS component declaration rather than each time in the HTML when adding a `<child>`?

Comment: Nope. You will have to explicitly state the props that the child component will receive from the parent. There's no implicit inheritance in VueJS.

Comment: No way to do that once somewhere rather than each time? If I have dozens of `<child>` components it's a real hassle to keep specifying it each time...

Comment: Is the number of child components driven by a list?

Comment: If you have a lot of child components that are iterative in nature, you might want to look into using `v-for`

Comment: @Bert no it isn't. This is a simplified example of my actual problem (in my actual problem there is content within the `<child>` components so they are unique).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a shared source of data.

```js
console.clear()

const shared = {
  message: "It works!"
}

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<p>{{shared.message}}</p>',
  data(){
    return {
      shared
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#theParent',
  data:{
    shared
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/2.3.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="theParent">
    <child></child>
    <child></child>
    <child></child>
    <button @click="shared.message = 'new message'">Change message</button>
</div>
```

Here, any time the `message` changes, it's available everywhere. This is essentially a *very* slim data management solution. For a more complete state management solution you may want to look into [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/), but you can go a very long way using a relatively simple shared data source and add in more complex solutions when you find you need them.

Comment: That looks like a great solution - I was under the impression that objects defined outside of `data()` may not be reactive and changes may not be reflected in the UI immediately...but it appears I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @abagshaw No problem ;) The difference here is that when `shared` is added to data, it is converted into a reactive object. If both the Vue and the component just used `shared` without it having been added to `data` and nothing else was done to make `shared` reactive, then it wouldn't be reactive.